# Multiply Data in Two Dataframes of Different Sizes and Keep Non-Similar Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to multiply data column-wise in two dataframes with different number of columns, but I don't want to return NaNs for the columns in the bigger dataframe. Say the dataframes are:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {
'A': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'B': ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
'C': [2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 7, 8],
'428': [1, 10, 5, 8, 2, 7, 10, 0, 3, 5],
'424': [9, 2, 6, 8, 9, 1, 7, 3, 8, 6],
'425': [4, 2, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 9, 9]
}

data2 = {
'428': [1, 10, 5, 8, 2, 7, 10, 0, 3, 5],
'424': [9, 2, 6, 8, 9, 1, 7, 3, 8, 6],
'425': [4, 2, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 9, 9]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

When I do `df1.mul(df2)` I get the following result:

```
   424  425  428   A   B   C
0   81   16    1 NaN NaN NaN
1    4    4  100 NaN NaN NaN
2   36   64   25 NaN NaN NaN
3   64   49   64 NaN NaN NaN
4   81   81    4 NaN NaN NaN
5    1   36   49 NaN NaN NaN
6   49  100  100 NaN NaN NaN
7    9   25    0 NaN NaN NaN
8   64   81    9 NaN NaN NaN
9   36   81   25 NaN NaN NaN
```

However, what I want to achieve is like the data below:

```
   424  425  428   A   B   C
0   81   16    1   3   D   2
1    4    4  100   3   D   4
2   36   64   25   3   D   1
3   64   49   64   3   D   0
4   81   81    4   3   D   2
5    1   36   49   3   D   1
6   49  100  100   3   D   3
7    9   25    0   3   D   0
8   64   81    9   3   D   7
9   36   81   25   3   D   8
```

I know I can achieve what I want by doing

```
df1['428'] = df1['428'] * df2['428']
df1['424'] = df1['424'] * df2['424']
df1['425'] = df1['425'] * df2['425']
```

However, because the columns that need to be multiplied are a lot, it's not the best solution. Also, I cannot do `df1.mul(df2, fill_value=1)` because `column B` in `df1` has strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
col=['428','424','425']

df1[col]=df1[col].mul(df2[col],axis=0,fill_value=1)
```